# How do I install the latest versions of Firefox and Thunderbird on my PC?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

Currently I have Firefox 45.02 and Thunderbird 38.6.0 installed on my PC.  I have downloaded Firefox 55.0.3 and Thunderbird 52.3.0 from the respective websites but how do I run and install these applications.  If I click on the downloads, all I get is a list of files but I do not see a setup-exe file anywhere.  I am not familiar with Linuc commands but what do I need to run and install.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04.  All responses would be appreciated.

Comment: This is Ubuntu you should be dealing with a `.deb` file

Comment: Open the **Software Updater** application, you should be seeing all available updates and able to update them by a single click.

Comment: unzip the file into /opt/ and start firefox with /opt/firefox{version}/firefox same for tbird.

Comment: @Rinzwind With the OP's apparent Linux skill level, I would strongly discourage installing such software manually...

Comment: I don't . There is nothing there that is newbie unfriendly. And answering this with an method that is NOT the latest is NOT answering the question. The correct order is: answer the question, add a reason why not to do that, add an Ubuntu method to get the latest as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Updating your software can be done in the Software Center or by typing the following command in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

This will update Firefox to **55.0.2** and Thunderbird to **52.2.1**, which are the versions currently supported by the official package sources.

You **can** install (even) newer software, however I do not recommend this. If it's not absolutely necessary, stick with the package sources. It may save you lots of trouble.

Comment: Nope. He wants the lastest version

Comment: @Rinzwind I know, but I won't recommend this, especially when it's not really necessary, as the package sources versions are not much behind.

Comment: Nevertheless. you answer is NOT answering the question. He asks for the newest, not an older version even if that is the latest in Ubuntu. The correct answer is to answer how to install the newest, then perhaps add a comment on why not to do this and then add what is your answer.

Comment: @Rinzwind Actually, OP asks for the latest versions, and I provide instructions to upgrade to the latest versions in the sources. Btw, why do you stop at the stable, isn't [the nightly build from today](https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/nightly/2017/08/2017-08-27-03-02-07-comm-esr52/) actually the **latest**? As *ByteCommander* points out it's apparant OP doesn't know how to upgrade software in Ubuntu and therefore tries it the Windows way, that's the only reason OP lists the versions online available.

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions so a gave a link for Thunderbird above then for firefox do:

1. Add the repo to your source list with:

   ```
   echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
   ```
2. Add repo digital signature:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
   ```
3. Update and install with:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install firefox-mozilla-build
   ```
4. Also if you wish add Thunderbird:

   ```
   sudo apt install thunderbird-mozilla-build
   ```
5. You will see two version when search for in `dash`, you may remove the default with:

   ```
    sudo apt remove firefox
   ```
6. And then the installed build version may be remove with:

   ```
    sudo apt remove firefox-mozilla-build
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> have downloaded Firefox 55.0.3 and Thunderbird 52.3.0 from the respective websites but how do I run and install these applications.

Extract the files in /opt/ and you can start both firefox and thunderbird from the created directories in there. Example for firefox, thunderbird is the same, just another directory:

```
$ cd /opt/firefox-55.0.2/
:/opt/firefox-55.0.2$ ./firefox
$ /opt/firefox-55.0.2/firefox --version 
Mozilla Firefox 55.0.2
```

Normal version will show the older one:

```
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 50.1.0
```

---

When you are a little bit into installing software this is not too difficult. Nevertheless... I would stick to the normal Ubuntu version; there is not a lot of benefit to the newest version that Ubuntu not yet has. All security related problems get added to our versions anyways.